# python float to string without precision loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

For python 3 I want to convert a float to a string, with possibly different length (i.e. number of digits) but with full precision.

Also I need to have a decimal point in any case:

```
1    -> '1.'
1/10 -> '0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'
```

currently my code is this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def formatMostSignificantDigits(x):
    out = str(Decimal(x))
    if out.find('.') < 0:
        out += '.'
    return out
```

can this be done more elegantly? (`e` notation would be possible, too)

Comment: I mean, I would use `endswith` instead of `.find < 0`, but other than that it looks fine. This would probably be better for codereview, as "more elegantly" isn't really something objective that we can give you.

Comment: @MorganThrapp How would `endswith` help with this problem?

Comment: @Selcuk Oh, you're right. Sorry, it's early.

Comment: I would have used `'.' in out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Pythons [string formatting functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
>>> x = 1.0; '{:.55f}'.format(x)
'1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> x = 1/10; '{:.55f}'.format(x)
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'
```

If you want to be able to feed it integers (such as `1`) as well, use `'{:.55f}'.format(float(x))`.

If you want to strip any trailing zeroes, use `'{:.55f}'.format(x).rstrip('0')`.

Note that 55 decimals after the point is way overkill (but it's what you showed in your question); 16 digits should suffice to express the full precision of double-precision IEEE 754 floats (20 digits for the 80-bit extended-precision you might encounter).

Comment: 55 digits is *not* overkill, if you want to print out the exact value of the float. 54 digits is not enough for `0.1`. Smaller numbers will need even more digits. The smallest positive Python `float` needs over 1000 digits (1074, to be precise) after the point to give the exact value.

Comment: this is the kind of solution I personally was looking for, a one-liner which is easy to understand

Comment: @MarkDickinson a double-precision float has 53 bits of precision (about 16 decimal digits' worth), so if you know the number originated as a float 16 digits is enough to represent the mantissa; anything more is effectively noise, as evidenced by `0.38410446334154735661295788101073491302710874766231638 == 0.38410446334154735 => True`. You're right about smaller values requiring more digit after the point though, I did not consider those. That could be fixed by using something like `{:.20e}`. Ultimately, which exact solution is appropriate depends on the _exact_ needs of the OP.

Comment: @marcelm: Yep. I read the OP's request as wanting enough digits to give the *exact* value of the float (which is also what conversion to `Decimal` achieves), in which case you need many digits after the point.

Comment: Also note that 16 *significant digits* (rather than places after the point) is in general not enough to distinguish two distinct IEEE 754 binary64 floats: you need 17 digits for that (which is why Python's `repr` in versions prior to Python 2.7 computed 17 significant digits and returned an output based on that computation).

Comment: You may want to look at the following as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298850/hexadecimal-string-representation-to-floating-number-in-python

Answer (score 2):

why do you use Decimal, you can just use:

```
x = 0.1
s = str(x)
print(s)   # this prints '0.1'
```

but if you use Decimal for something else than instead of this:

```
out = str(Decimal(x))
if out.find('.') < 0:
    out += '.'
return out
```

you can just use:

```
return Decimal(x).__str__()
```

Edit 1:

also good module for float precision is bigfloat:

```
from bigfloat import BigFloat
x = 0.1
print(BigFloat(x, precision(300)).__str__())
# thsi will print'0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045410156250000000000000000000000000000000000000'
# but if you use this:
print(BigFloat(x.__str__(), precision(300)).__str__())
# it can be precise as much as you want
print(BigFloat(x.__str__(), precision(100000)).__str__()) # try this
```

Comment: when you vote down please say what is the reason you are doing it.

Comment: I appreciate your solution, especially the `BigFloat` hint, thanks