# Hexadecimal string representation to floating number in python

Tags: python-3.x, numeric

From python documentation says that "the hexadecimal string 0x3.a7p10 represents the floating-point number (3 + 10./16 + 7./16**2) * 2.0**10, or 3740.0" so :

```
>>> float.fromhex('0x3.a7p10')

3740.0
```

then

```
>>> float.hex(3740.0)

'0x1.d380000000000p+11' (will give different presentation)
```

My question is how to convert '0x1.d380000000000p+11' in to floating number using calculation formula above and why classmethod float.hex and classmethod float.fromhex give different presentation.

Thankyou....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'0x1.d380000000000p+11'` means `(1 + 13./16 + 3./16**2 + 8/16**3) * 2.0**11`, which is equal to `3740.0`. To convert this result, you can run `float.fromhex('0x1.d380000000000p+11')` which returns `3740.0` again.

`float.hex` gives you a *normalized* representation, which means that the factor in front of the `2**x` is between 1 and 2. What the interpreter did, was shift the comma in the binary representation by one position: increase the exponent (from 10 to 11), and half the factor (`0x3.a7 / 2 = 0x1.d38`).

In general, in this *normalized* representation, the factor in front is between 1 and the base. For example, if you do `print(2234.2e-34)`, you get `2.2342e-31`. Here the leading factor is between 1 and 10 because `e` corresponds to `10**x`.

Comment: yes to convert the result is using float.fromhex but my question is how to convert using the "first formula" (3 + 10./16 + 7./16\**2) * 2.0**10, I still not get it.... thanks

Comment: where did numbers 13, 3, and 8 come from (numbers which devided by 16)....?

Comment: Ok i get it where 13, 3, and 8 come from... Thanks

Comment: Hi @WiraBhakti if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.